# Did I commit a great sin by having intercourse with my same-sex cousin, and will Allah forgive me?

Tags: sex, homosexuality, tawba

My cousin and I were alone last night and we were bored. He tempted me to have intercourse with him. I'm a boy and so is he. It was such a situation for me that I couldn't reject, but now I am very guilty about my deed. He is so attractive that I couldn't reject and he  requested me, so I thought if I reject it may hurt him, so I had a gay intercourse with him.

Have I committed a great sin? Will Allah forgive me?

Comment: for your first question, yes you have committed an enormous sin. The people of the prophet Lut AS were destroyed for homosexual acts.  However, whether Allah SWT will forgive you or not is not for anyone to judge. As a muslim your responsibility now is to repent to him and ask for forgiveness, and thats all you can do. Have hope that He will forgive you and fear that He wont. However remember that Allah SWT is the most merciful and forgiving, and May He forgive us all for our sins. Amen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to be a muslim and have a gay sex?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23635/9123)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to be a Muslim and have a gay sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23635/is-it-okay-to-be-a-muslim-and-have-a-gay-sex)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer will be deleted, but, even if for a lot of Muslims an homosexual intercourse is prohibited, others think it's not.
In the history of Sodom and Lut the population was not punished because of homosexual behavior, but because of many other things, like inhospitality, and rudeness. As many have done, you can read between the lies also the presence of homosexuality, but you have to nit-pick.

Don't be afraid, God will forgive you. Actually there is nothing to forgive, I read all the Quu'ran and I coudn't find something really against homosexuality. So Just be yourself. As you can see, many read the quu'ran with their Point of view, and try to impose it on others too. Many Muslims are doing bad things, and they state that Islams says to do so. that's their pov, so why ant we have our own? It's just have to  have the purpose of doing good thing, be a good person and help others, That's how it should be. Yes, I'm muslim.

Comment: Please consider adding evidences for your claims

Answer (score 0):

In Quran, Allah say -
إِنَّ اللّهَ لاَ يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ ذَلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاء وَمَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللّهِ فَقَدْ 
ضَلَّ ضَلاَلاً بَعِيدًا
Translation :
Verily ! Allah will not pardon those who associate a partner with Him. Apart from him, He will pardon all others . Who ascribe partners to Allah has gone far astray.

وَاللَّـهُ غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ 
Translation :
And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

and finally -
"O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." -sura JUMAR.

Read Istegfar more and more , love Allah and don't do this again.

Comment: Please don't confound ISE with a typical internet forum, we expect answers here to be well elaborated focused on answering the actual question and your claims to be supported by evidences (see [answer]). BTW I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help] to make yourself familiar with this site and the SE model.