# Is this person considered a Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram

bad=
Does not pray, does not fast, does not go to hajj, does not care if food is halal or not

Good=
Doesn't drink alcohol
Doesn't eat pork
Gives zakat
Is kind to parents 
Is clean

Comment: Answer to a related question could shed some lightL http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25850/549

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to judge another person rather than about the academic study of Islam.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one does not go outside the fold of Islam unless he commits major shirk, denies one of the things that has been made wajib(obligatory) by the religion, or certain other specific acts. Major sins other than shirk do not take you outside of Islam. However, if he doesn't make salah and doesn't fast in Ramadan because he doesn't believe these things these things are obligatory, then he is a kafir, as he is disbelieving in those ayat of the Qur'an and ahadith where those things were clearly made haram.

To answer a question to the answer above, homosexual acts are a grave sin but not an act of kufr(disbelief). Even a Muslim who feels homosexual urges and commits homosexual acts is still a Muslim while he believes

1. In Allah wa dahu la sharika lah(without partners)
2. That homosexual acts are haram, and if commits those acts he is making a sin.

Wallahu alam(And Allah Knows Best)

Comment: Indeed a nice and detailed answer. Thank you for sharing!!

Comment: you begin your answer with "yes" and then it appears that your answer is "no". i dislike this.

Comment: you mean homosexual sex? is not it also clearly made haram?! it is also written in quran as salat is written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Without any doubt he is a muslim but he is not a good Muslim. A Muslim is one who believes there is no God except Allah. Allah has no sons or daughters. He is not son of anybody. Muhammad is his last messenger.

Comment: Even if he is gay he is considered in Muslim if he believes Allah I the only God?

Comment: The link Shoaib mentioned answers that question well in detail which I can't do explain in comments. Would you mind to read that once?

Comment: i think, what you say about is mu'min, not muslim.

Comment: @qdinar A nice point indeed! But you know that some people don't understand the difference between these two! And you even know that some people even don't know what is a moumin therefore for sake of simplicity I used the word Muslim.. If I had said Moumin then I would have confused the question asker and He would say "Hey, wait a minute! Now what is a moumin?"